# How to search for more than one file at a time using Windows?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, windows-search, file-search

I have 1,015 images in a folder and these images is classified into seven categories of medical diagnoses of skin cancer, and the same images are classified in the Excel file by number (the number of each image corresponds to the type of diagnosis of this image). The type of image is labelled as "dx".  Clearly, each image has a specific number corresponding to the diagnostic type, my question is How do I search for a group of files by copying their names from the Excel file and then paste them in the search box in Windows at once. In other words i want to take the names of a hundred images from  the Excel file then search for them by pasting their names in the search box. Can I do that or do I need a particular tool?

[images folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL2fS.jpg)
[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyNtu.png) 
[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwpvW.png)

Comment: Refer to this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-can-i-search-for-multiple-files-at-once/983e0ec8-71ef-418c-9fba-eacee8d12254?auth=1

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add an OR within spaces between the search parameters (filenames)

[image]

To create this querie add " OR " in the next column of your file and then just select everything to copy paste it.

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to write OR when i need to search of 50 files or 100 files at once

Comment: @AhmadSarairah write your search criteria with a formula in Excel, if you have 2016 you should be able to use a function called `TEXTJOIN`

Comment: @AhmadSarairah or just write " OR "in the column next to the filename and then select everything for copy paste

Comment: I need to copy 50 names from the Excel column and paste them into the search box, but the problem only copies one name in the search box and this is my problem

Comment: thats the line break. Put everything in one line with @PeterH 's suggestion

Comment: I tried to do this but I did not get the desired result

Comment: @AhmadSarairah using the image above, in Cell C2 use `=TEXTJOIN("OR",TRUE,A1:A10)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

- Download "Everything" (search-app)
  https://www.voidtools.com/
  (I suggest you download the "portable" version. Just extract the contents to a folder, and run the app. Afterwards you can simply delete the folder.)
- Then do as veritaS suggested.
  Create a column in Excel to the right of the filenames. Fill it with "OR". Select the cells of both columns and press "Copy".
- Now "Paste" into the searchfield of the "Everything"-app.

If you wish to move the files into folders. You can just drag'n'drop or cut+paste the files from the search results in "Everything" to a windows-explorer window.

Comment: In case you don't know: You only need to write "OR" once. Then select the cell. In the bottom right corner of the cell will be a small dot. Left-click and hold on that dot, now drag your mouse down over the empty cells below. Once you let go of the mouse-button, "OR" will be copied into all those cells.

Comment: I worked the steps as above but when I pasted the names in the search field , then I pressed enter  nothing appears